# Google Maps API - Geocode - Postman get ZERO_RESULTS vs Browser get OK

Tags: rest, google-maps, postman, google-maps-api-2

The request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TV%20FRANCISCO%20VIGNOLI%2C%2053%2C%20CENTRO&components=administrative_area:SAQUAREMA|administrative_area:RJ|country:br&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Get the results:

`{
   "results": [],
   "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}`

[image: Postman]

But when I use the browser get `"status": "OK"`

[image: Firefox]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please don't post (only) pictures of code or responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the trick is that your browser adds some additional information in the request headers. For example, browser may know your regional settings and language, so adding this information might help Google to bias results towards specific region.

Probably, the `TV FRANCISCO VIGNOLI, 53, CENTRO` doesn't bring any relevant results for English speaking persons, but it can find something relevant for Portuguese speaking users.

In your example, if I execute the query from postman

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TV%20FRANCISCO%20VIGNOLI%2C%2053%2C%20CENTRO&key=MY_API_KEY`

I get ZERO_RESULTS.

But if I add region parameter in the request and bias results towards Brasil

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TV%20FRANCISCO%20VIGNOLI%2C%2053%2C%20CENTRO&region=BR&key=MY_API_KEY`

I get the response

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "address_components":[
    {
      "long_name":"LOJA 01",
      "short_name":"LOJA 01",
      "types":[
        "subpremise"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"53",
      "short_name":"53",
      "types":[
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"Tv Francisco Vignoli",
      "short_name":"Tv Francisco Vignoli",
      "types":[
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"Centro",
      "short_name":"Centro",
      "types":[
        "political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"Saquarema",
      "short_name":"Saquarema",
      "types":[
        "administrative_area_level_2","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"Rio de Janeiro",
      "short_name":"RJ",
      "types":[
        "administrative_area_level_1","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"Brazil",
      "short_name":"BR",
      "types":[
        "country","political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name":"28990-774",
      "short_name":"28990-774",
      "types":[
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Tv Francisco Vignoli, 53 - LOJA 01 - Centro, Saquarema - RJ, 28990-774, Brazil",
      "geometry":{
    "location":{
      "lat":-22.9325062,"lng":-42.4960983
    },
    "location_type":"ROOFTOP",
    "viewport":{
      "northeast":{
        "lat":-22.9311572197085,"lng":-42.4947493197085
      },
      "southwest":{
        "lat":-22.9338551802915,"lng":-42.4974472802915
      }
    }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJbZ-VwgNflwARDpn0-ZA19Xs",
      "plus_code":{
    "compound_code":"3G83+XH Centro, Saquarema - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","global_code":"589V3G83+XH"
      },
      "types":[
    "establishment","health","point_of_interest","store"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status":"OK"
}
```

At this point it looks like your browser is intelligent enough to send a regional information to Google backend server.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Yeah, that is simple and I didn't think about it. Already works here! Tks @xomena

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you Accept-Language header
'Accept-Language'=>'Fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'
More information here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Answer (score 0):

[Your link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TV%20FRANCISCO%20VIGNOLI%2C%2053%2C%20CENTRO&components=administrative_area:SAQUAREMA|administrative_area:RJ|country:br&key=) doesn't work in the browser for me (when I add my own key).

Looks like the address the Geocoder knows is:

> Tv. Francisco Vignole, 53 - Campo Aviacao, Saquarema - RJ, 28990-000, Brazil

[This request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Francisco%20Vignole,53%20Campo%20Aviacao&components=administrative_area:SAQUAREMA|administrative_area:RJ|country:br&key=) works for me in both my browser and postman (when I add a key):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Francisco%20Vignole,53%20Campo%20Aviacao&components=administrative_area:SAQUAREMA|administrative_area:RJ|country:br&key=
```

Comment: You change the URL, doesn't have **Tv.** and I know that the sublocality is **Campo Aviacao** not **CENTRO**. I'm trying to understand how the same URL using the browser works and using any other tool don't to make the same request

Comment: [Your link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TV%20FRANCISCO%20VIGNOLI%2C%2053%2C%20CENTRO&components=administrative_area:SAQUAREMA|administrative_area:RJ|country:br&key=) doesn't work in my browser (when I add a valid key, it returns `"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"`).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The link works for me but is it a valid address anyway? When I make requests on valid addresses anywhere in the world, I get the same results with Postman and my browser too.